# Why is my simple MATLAB gradient descend for linear regression not working

Tags: matlab, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am starting to learn linear regression. I wanted to implement gradient descend by myself. I wrote the code below.

```
%% Linear regression

close all;

dataset =load('accidents');
data = dataset.hwydata;
x = data(:,14);
y  =data(:,4);
%% Gradient descent
% We want to minimize a cost function and GD achieves that iteratively.
% J(w,b) =(y-y_est)^2

w = 0;
b = 0;
alpha =.000001; % I tried various alphas like 0.01, .1 etc. (Not working)
for i =1: 100
    y_est = w*x + b;
    J = mean((y-y_est).^2)
    temp_w = w + alpha*(mean(x.*(y-w*x-b)));
    temp_b = b + alpha*(mean(y-w*x-b));
    w =temp_w
    b =temp_b
end
```

For some reason, it is not working. It seems like my algorithm is not converging.

I expected the algorithm to converge nicely because the mean squared error cost function is convex.

Comment: What are the ranges of values of x & y? A possible cause for the algorithm to diverge is very large values of x & y, which makes the gradient too large compared to alpha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer: You need some sort of line search along the direction of the gradient.

As I mentioned in my inquire, large values of x and y can cause the algorithm to diverge, and that is what is happening in your program, there are x values up to approx. 3e7 and the initial value of the partial derivative w.r.t. w is about 1e10.

For a very crude and simple line search: compare the current merit function (`Jcurrent` in the code below) with the one calculated with `temp_w`, `temp_b`, and the current alpha (`Jnew` in the code below).

If `Jnew >= Jcurrent` reduce alpha by some factor and recalculate `temp_w` and `temp_b` with the new alpha and current gradient. Recalculate `Jnew` with the updated `temp_w` and `temp_b`. Repeat until `Jnew < Jcurrent`.

After this line search you have at least two options: 1) Reset alpha to its starting value  (`alphaOrig` in the code) or 2) Keep the current alpha.

Notice that this line search is *very far* from optimal. It searches only for a reduction in the merit function and accepts it regardless of how small the reduction is. This causes slow convergence. Let me know if you want me to suggest better line-search approaches.

JAC

```
%% Linear regression

clear; 
% Delete all figures
figureList = findobj('type', 'figure');
if ~isempty(figureList)
    delete(figureList);
end
    alphaOrig = 1e-4;
    dataset =load('accidents');
    data = dataset.hwydata;
    x = data(:,14);
    y  =data(:,4);
% ..Check the ranges of x and y    
    fprintf(1, 'max(x) = %g\tmax(y) = %g\n', max(abs(x)), max(abs(y)) );
%% Gradient descent
% We want to minimize a cost function and GD achieves that iteratively.
% J(w,b) =(y-y_est)^2

    w = 0;
    b = 0;
    alpha = alphaOrig;
% ..Initial value of merit function
    Jcurrent = mean((y - w*x - b).^2);
    for i =1: 100
        y_est = w*x + b;
        J = mean((y-y_est).^2);
    % ..Components of the gradient (actually, minus gradient)
        dJdw = mean(x.*(y-w*x-b));
        dJdb = mean(y-w*x-b);
        fprintf(1, '%d: J(%g,%g) = %.8g\t', i, w,b,Jcurrent);
        fprintf(1, 'dJ/dw = %g; dJ/db = %g\n', dJdw, dJdb);
    % ..Crude line search
        while true % Loop not in the original at stackoverflow
            temp_w = w + alpha*dJdw;
            temp_b = b + alpha*dJdb;
            Jnew = mean((y - temp_w*x - temp_b).^2);
            fprintf(1, '\talpha = %g;\tJ(%g,%g) = %.8g; \n', ...
                alpha, temp_w, temp_b, Jnew);
            if Jnew < Jcurrent
                break;
            end
            alpha = 0.1*alpha; % <== reduce alpha
            if alpha == 0
                error("Sorry. It's not going well");
            end
        end
        Jcurrent = Jnew;
%         alpha = alphaOrig; % This resets alpha
        w =temp_w;
        b =temp_b;
    end
    fmt = "%10s: w = %g; b= %g\n";
    fprintf(1, fmt, "Estimate", w, b);
    fig = figure(1);clf
    plot(x,y, 'linestyle', 'none','marker', 'o');
    hold on
% ..Show the least-squares fit
    t = [0.9*min(x),1.2*max(x)];
    plot(t,w*t+b, 'linestyle', '--', 'color', 'black');
```

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense now. I missed to update the alpha as you suggested.